# how to batch get a series of URLs with parameters

Tags: wget

I have to retrieve content of a URL with different parameters for batch processing, for example:

http://www.sitenmae.com/process.php?type=aa&menu=detail&itemid=12345

I need to get itemid from let's say 12345 to 12445.

I tried to do (under bash)

wget 'http://www.sitenmae.com/process.php?type=aa&menu=detail&itemid=12{345..445}'

but it doesn't work. Can someone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple sh with `for` loop and download it

```
for i in {12345..12445}
do
   echo "Downloading item $i"
   wget http://www.sitenmae.com/process.php?type=aa&menu=detail&itemid=$i
done
```